# SL Decomposition of $\begin{pmatrix} 5 & -4 \\ 9 & -7 \end{pmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, matrix-decomposition

I want to find a decomposition of this matrix in the form of 
$$
A^{n_1} \cdot B \cdot A^{n_2} \cdot B \cdots B \cdot A^{n_k}
$$
where
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \quad \text{and} \quad
B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
I am aware that $A^n = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & n \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, but fail at using the Euclidean algorithm as in  [Example 2.1](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/SL%282,Z%29.pdf) to find a decomposition.

I tried using results from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1260396/algorithm-to-generate-an-arbitrary-matrix-of-special-linear-group-sl2-mathbb/1260476#comment5750622_1260476), but that didn´t help me, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to multiply on the left at each stage, the final "answer," well, you work it out

$$   B \mapsto
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
9&-7 \\
-5&4 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$   A^2 \mapsto
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
-1&1 \\
-5&4 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$   B \mapsto
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
-5&4 \\
1&-1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$   A^{5} \mapsto
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0&-1 \\
1&-1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$   B \mapsto
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1&-1 \\
0&1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$   A \mapsto
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1&0 \\
0&1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: So the answer ist $B^{-1} A^{-2} B^{-1} A^{-5} B^{-1} A^{-1}$.